# Charging credit card via Magento admin new order using Authorize.Net

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, payment, magento-1.9, authorize.net

Some of our customers provide their credit card information through the phone or emails to buy merchandises. Items are expensive and the way to avoid fraud transactions, we are using Signifyd.com and other services to protect ourselves. 
We have Virtual Terminals to charge customers but by this way, they will not check for any fraud possibilities. 
(We are using Athorized.net as the merchant account)
By adding a new order in Magento admin panel, we have an option to fill the credit card information in payment section. But it gets error while saving the order (Gateway error: This transaction cannot be accepted)This error is generated when your Authorize.Net account is in Password-Required Mode and you are not sending a valid Transaction Key.
[screen shot for payment option in admin new order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WudNp.png)

Is there any way to charge the card through admin panel by making a new order?
.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: try placing orders from frontend.